# Vector of integer datetimes to matlab durations

Tags: matlab

How do I convert a vector of integers that represent time in microseconds since the unix epoch into matlab durations suitable for use in timetables?

```
datetimes = [1679909400000000;1679909500000000;1679909600000000]
```

Comment: Maybe [this might help](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/443535-convert-unix-time-in-date-time-format-with-milliseconds)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ConvertFrom='posixtime'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html#d124e330843) in the `datetime` constructor to do this, after dividing by `1e6` to get seconds from the POSIX epoch. You can get a `datetime` representing the POSIX epoch by passing in the value 0.

```
>> timePoints =  datetime(datetimes/1e6, ConvertFrom = 'posixtime')

timePoints = 

  3x1 datetime array

   27-Mar-2023 09:30:00
   27-Mar-2023 09:31:40
   27-Mar-2023 09:33:20

>> timeSinceEpoch = timePoints - datetime(0, ConvertFrom = 'posixtime')

timeSinceEpoch = 

  3x1 duration array

   466641:30:00
   466641:31:40
   466641:33:20
```

Comment: how do I make it a duration by subtracting the unix epoch?

Comment: I added this to the answer